# Algorithm for implementing pedigree Chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

There are an array of objects grabbed from database as shown below

```
    const users = [
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", fatherId: 4, motherId: 5, spouseId: 3, children:[] },
  { id: 3, name: "Mary", fatherId: 6, motherId: 7, spouseId: 2, children:[] },
  { id: 4, name: "Tom", fatherId: null, motherId: null, spouseId: 5, children:[{id:2}] },
  { id: 5, name: "Sue", fatherId: null, motherId: null, spouseId: 4, children:[{id:2}] },
  { id: 6, name: "Jim", fatherId: null, motherId: null, spouseId: 7, children:[{id:3}] },
  { id: 7, name: "Jill", fatherId: null, motherId: null, spouseId: 6, children:[{id:3}] },
];
```

I am trying to draw a pedigree chart from this array of objects looping through
individual objects and drawing respective parents, spouses, and children.
But this is affecting the performance when calculating the x and y also, some elements overlapping when drawn when there is an increase in the number of objects (hierarchy).

Is there an algorithm to draw the chart neatly.

[image]

I am trying to draw as shown in above figure, which automatically adjust x and y position when parents, siblings, children are added to each element dynamically.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151296/family-tree-with-pure-html-and-css-or-with-minimal-js

Comment: Check https://graphviz.org/

Comment: Are there any other option than using third party libraries because I need to implement this inside another library

Comment: @DustinBun _"Are there any other option than using third party libraries?"_ - no, not really: graph-visualization is a hard problem ([NP-hard, in fact](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9090110X)). Granted, I'm sure we've all tried our hand at programming drawing (LOGO in school, GDI, JS Canvas 2D, OpenGL, etc) and we all quickly learned how soon it stops being _fun_ and starts being tiresome. There really is no shame in using D3 or an existing library, because why reinvent the wheel when you could be delivering value?

Comment: @Dai  I need to use this library for drawing the above diagram, 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pedigree-chart , is it possible to integrate d3 with this.

Comment: @DustinBun That library you're linking to is dependency-free, why are you asking about D3?

Comment: I need to draw a dynamic chart using this library ( npmjs.com/package/pedigree-chart ).
User will be able to add parents,children's to each element by clicking on the element drawn. The problem is the elements get overlapped when drawing.
I need a way to determine the x and y of each element so they look tidy ( in the form of a tree ) @Dai